# HTTP response body from `Arc<[u8]>` in Actix-web?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm writing a web server using Actix-web. I have a cache component that stores some data as `Arc<[u8]>`, now I'd like to send these directly without making an unnecessary copy.

I didn't find any direct way to do this, so I've tried to figure out how to implement the `MessageBody` trait for my wrapper type, but I'm getting stuck on converting `Arc<[u8]>` to `actix_web::web::Bytes`. The docs actually talk about `Bytes` supporting `Arc`, but I can't find any way to actually use that.

What is the best way to serve `Arc<[u8]>` body in Actix-web?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if `Arc` support was never finished in `bytes`. There is a [`KIND_ARC`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/src/bytes/bytes.rs.html#1057) constant used in the internal vtable implementations, but I can't see anywhere that actually creates a vtable with this kind. Under the hood, `Bytes` does reference counting when cloned. Could you perhaps change your cache component to store `Bytes` values instead of `Arc<[u8]>`? Semantically they are nearly identical.

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly (although I liked the way that `Arc<[u8]>` explicitly describes the behavior more :-) ), . Could you please turn this into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that `Bytes` is a reference-counted and copy-on-write container for a byte array, it's semantically very similar to `Arc<[u8]>` but with some extra features. I would suggest changing your cache to store `Bytes` values instead of `Arc<[u8]>` and then the problem goes away.